# Can Android default SMS NOT handle MMS?

Tags: android, mms

So I am struggling a lot with making an API19+ default SMS app. The SMS part is easy, well documented and clear. But when it comes to MMS, the web is silent.

In order to be a default SMS app on Android, the app must define `intent-filter`s for both sms and mms:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="sms" />
     <data android:scheme="smsto" />
     <data android:scheme="mms" />
     <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

But there is no easy way to handle MMS on Android, there are many setbacks and some devices are known not to work with custom MMS apps, so Id like to avoid this and delegate all MMS related work to another app (the original Android default SMS app). Is that possible? How?

Alternatively, do you know of any example of sending and receiving MMS on Android API 19+?

Thanks

Comment: When an app is not the default SMS app, it's expected to disable its messaging functionalities to allow the default app to correctly send, receive, and store messages. If yours is default, it's responsible for everything MMS, and the stock messaging app will most likely not allow you to even attempt to send from it. So, no, it's not really possible to hand off your responsibilities as default, at least not everywhere consistently. The project referenced in the link-only answer below is the one I see most commonly referenced when this issue comes up, but I cannot vouch for its efficacy.

Comment: Problem is, def sms app have to take care of mms sending and yet mms sending using custom code fails for unknown reason on some devices (see issue list on link in answer below from ifeegoo). So there actually is no way of making a fully functional custom default sms app...

Comment: It's possible, it's just not trivial.

Comment: I would also mention that no third-party messaging app works absolutely everywhere, so, ya know, if yours works on at least a majority of devices, it's perfectly reasonable to add a disclaimer that it might not on some systems.